# Only push files with certain extensions to GitHub

Tags: git, gitignore

I am working on a data analysis project whose directory structure looks like following

```
pipeline1.py
pipeline2.py
...
pipelineN.py
data/
config/
test/
```

where folder `data/` mixes a lot of data processing Python scripts and raw data.

Now I am almost done with the data preprocessing in `data/` and ready to commit changes to my personal GitHub repo. However, I am not sure how could I push only `.py` in this folder.

I have tried adding following to `.gitignore` but this will ignore the `data/` entirely and hence not desirable.

```
!*.py

data/
```

Comment: replace `data/` with `!data/*.py`

Comment: Note that you can't select individual files when you push. You can only push whole commits along with their complete history. If you've already committed other files, you will have to [rewrite your commits](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Answer (score 0):

You should use that way:

#### first ignore everything in that folder

data/

#### than except those files

!data/*.py